# I don't need to be dropped off

Tags: meaning

I'm making a booking for a regular maintenance of my car.

They ask me:

> While we are servicing your vehicle
>
> - I don't need to be dropped off, or
> - I will wait at the dealership

What's the meaning of "I don't need to be dropped off"? Does it mean I will just leave the car with them and go away?

Comment: I'll note that, in the US, it would be more idiomatic to hear something like "Do you need to use the shuttle?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, on the meaning of dropping off someone or something, from [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drop-off-something-someone)

> **drop off something/someone**
>
> *phrasal verb with drop verb*
>
> to take someone or something, esp. by car, to a particular place:
>
> > I’m about to leave – can I drop you off somewhere on my way home?

Secondly, on its usage in the context of the question:

Since you cannot use your car while it is being serviced, some people may expect that the dealership will drop you off somewhere (and maybe come and pick you up later and bring you back to the dealership, when the service is completed).

This question is an indirect way of telling you that they will not do that. It indicates that your only two options are that you will find your own way to wherever you wish to go while waiting for the car to be serviced, or you'll just wait at the dealership. It is indirect because it doesn't just say "We do not provide dropoff services for customers while their car is being serviced". Instead, it

- doesn't list dropping you off somewhere as an option
- explicitly lists *not* dropping you off as an option ("I don't need to be dropped off")

Comment: Your answer does not seem to address the meaning, in this context, of the phrasal verb "to drop off" (transitive.) "**to drop** [someone or something] **off** [at a place]" = to take someone or something to a [convenient] place in a vehicle and leave them/it there.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make it clear why you think that the question is an indirect way of saying that they don't offer drop-off service. If they are asking the question, why would they be telling you that dropping you off somewhere is not an option? If they wanted to say that, they could just say it. They are asking you this: "Would you like for us to drop you off somewhere, or would you prefer to wait here while we service your car?" That's pretty frequent practice.

Comment: @Greybeard Thanks, updated to add that.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Thanks. I was trying to say, they are *not* giving you that option, as they are only giving you the option "I *don't* need to be dropped off". Since "I need to be dropped off" is not listed as an option, that is indirectly saying it is not an option. Have edited the answer to hopefully state that more clearly.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. Very detailed explanaiton!

Comment: @SevernSevern Glad it helped. Thanks to Greybeard and Isabel Archer for pointing out things that were missing in my earlier answer.

Comment: Of course, it is not unknown for a list to contain inconsistencies of polarity.  https://bendwavy.org/wp/?p=19